# WebAPI & SignalR web application - Authenticating & Authorizing

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a `WebAPI` solution and I use `token authentication`, so the flow is the following:

- user tries to login using the `username` and `password`
- if the  credentials are correct, he is given a token in order to use in the following requests (to be placed in the header  of the `AJAX` requests).

Now `SignalR` comes into play.  Since it uses `WebSockets`, you are not able to pass a header. 
Searching for a solution, I've come across the following:

1. Actually pass a header to  `SignalR` - not  an option since it forces `SignalR` to use `longPolling`.

`$.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = { Authorization: "Bearer " + token };`

2. Pass the same `token` used for authenticating `WebAPI` calls as a `query string`/or store it in a cookie for `SignalR`, then create a provider that somehow unwraps and expands the token into identity. [I followed this blog post](http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/05/authentication-with-signalr-and-oauth.html#.VelcDPmqqko) but I seem to be missing something.
3. Again pass the token as a `query string`/or as a cookie, but this time create a custom `Authorize Attribute` to `Authorize` `SignalR` hubs or methods.
   [Again a blog post about this.](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2014/05/27/set-context-user-principal-for-customized-authentication-in-signalr.aspx) The problem with this solution was in `Unprotect` method on the token.
4. The final and the easiest solution is to also enable `cookie  authentication`, keep using `bearer token authentication` for `WebAPI` calls and let the `OWIN Middleware` authorize calls on the hubs. (this solution actually works).

Now, the issue is that using the default template for a `WebAPI` application with `Individual User Accounts` (so with token authentication), whenever I send an `AJAX` request to the `API` it also sends the cookie.

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());


            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        }
    }



public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Even if I did this:

```
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

Authorization: Bearer 2bTw5d8Vf4sKR9MNMqZsxIOPHp5qtXRTny5YEC_y7yWyrDLU0__q8U8Sbo7N7XBjPmxZXP18GRXjDVb3yQ9vpQnWXppRhVA8KDeGg2G5kITMxiOKvGMaKwyUGpORIeZ0UHyP9jA2fX9zPwzsCqHmq-LoGKls0MQNFjXgRGCCCvro5WPMAJcLs0kUoD_2W_TOTy9_T-koobw-DOivnazPo2Z-6kfXaIUuZ1YKdAbcSJKzpyPR_XrCt4Ma2fCf-LcpMPGo4gDFKfxWdId0XtfS9S-5cXmmOmGM4Y6MkAUK8O9sZlVrpmpvV0hjXF2QwfLtQViPyEctbTr1vPBNn014n60APwGSGnbUJBWMvJhqcjI5pWoubCmk7OHJrn052U_F3bDOi2ha1mVjvhVY1XMAuv2c3Pbyng2ZT_VuIQI7HjP4SLzV6JjRctfIPLEh67-DFp585sJkqgfSyM6h_vR2gPA5hDocaFs73Qa22QMaLRrHThU0HM8L3O8HgFl5oJtD
Referer: http://localhost:15379/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6
Cookie: .AspNet.Cookies=E71BnnTMv8JJ4hS9K46Y2yIbGMQCTS4MVBWBXezUYCSGXPbUPNZh98Q0IElQ0zqGyhB7OpYfdh10Kcy2i5GrWGSiALPPtOZUmszfAYrLZwG2JYiU5MSW80OGZVMY3uG2U1aqvvKJpv7eJwJSOoS4meD_3Qy8SwRzTg8feZArAE-REEXSsbPfq4jQBUUbxfDAyuPVRsLNfkn4oIAwZTs85IulRZI5mLnLqOS7VLejMGIWhkuyOWvvISu1pjsP5FMDXNwDkjv2XCaOpRzZYUxBQJzkcdpDjwW_VO2l7HA263NaG_IBqYpLqG57Fi-Lpp1t5Deh2IRB0VuTqAgrkwxifoBDCCWuY9gNz-vNjsCk4kZc8QKxf7el1gu9l38Ouw6K1EZ9y2j6CGWmW1q-DobaK9JXOQEPm_LGyaGPM5to2vchTyjuieZvLBAjxhLKnXdy34Z7MZXLVIwmpSmyPvmbIuH9QzOvTWD-I1AQFJyCDw8
```

Do you see an easier way of authenticating `SignalR` with token authentication? Is this final approach  (if I manage to suppress the sending of the cookie with requests) viable  in production?

Comment: I have not tried yet, however, here are 2 links you can refer if you have not read yet: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security and http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

Comment: Perhaps another links for your issue [here](http://blog.shaunxu.me/archive/2014/05/27/set-context-user-principal-for-customized-authentication-in-signalr.aspx) and [here](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/popup-oauth-authentication-with-aspnet-and-signalr). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working on that particular project, I ended up simply using cookie authentication and CSRF, but I was still interested in seeing how to authenticate WebApi and SignalR using bearer token authentication.

[For a working sample, please see this GitHub repository.](https://github.com/microsoft-dx/aspnet-fundamentals/tree/master/AspNetFundamentals/aspnet04%20-%20SimpleTokenAuthentication)

I ended up creating an `OAuthBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider` class that tries to retrieve the token from the cookie.

```
public class OAuthBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
        {
            var tokenCookie = context.OwinContext.Request.Cookies["BearerToken"];

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenCookie))
                context.Token = tokenCookie;

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

And here is the method in the `Startup` class that deals with authentication:

```
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Provider = new OAuthBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider()
        });

    }
```

[For a working sample, please see this GitHub repository.](https://github.com/microsoft-dx/aspnet-fundamentals/tree/master/AspNetFundamentals/aspnet04%20-%20SimpleTokenAuthentication)

Hope this helps someone at some point.

Comment: A link to your repo is broken. Could you add a working link please?